# Difference in covariant/contravariant indexation order in Tensors

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation, covariance

**Warning:** You might be wondering why this isn’t in Math Stack Exchange. In fact, it is. I asked the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2804652/11127) there a few days ago but got no answer, and since I think that this question is more directed towards the “physicist POV” of tensors and is related to Einstein’s Convention, I’ll leave the question here.

*Original Question Below*

I'm trying to self study tensor calculus. I was trying to derive the notation for covariant and contravariant indexes of a linear transformation matrix ($(1,1)$ type tensor).

So I did the following: Try for the $2 \times 2$ case, and then try to find a pattern.

For covectors (covariant) $x_i$: (I shall first assume that both indexes of the matrix are up as contravariant, just for simplicity of notation. I'll later "correct" this according to what i have found).

We have:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x_1' & x_2 ' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a^{11} & a^{12} \\ a^{21} & a^{22} \end{bmatrix}$$
And so, for $x_j'$, I'll have:
$$x_j' = a^{ij}x_i$$
(Summation convention here). Here, I am summing on the *first* index of the matrix.
For the contravariant case, I have:
$$x^i ‘= a^{ij}v^j$$
Hence summing on the *second* index of the matrix. So, I tought about writing $a$ as $a_{i}^j$, calling then $i$ as the *covariant* index and $j$ as the *contravariant* index. **Does this make any sense?** The first problem I see is that this goes against the summation convention, who states that the indexes must be summed up when they are at different positions (ex: $a^iv_i$ would mean a summation in $i$, but $a_ iv_i$ would not).

This construction I've made would be equivalent to:
$$a = a_ib^j \mathbf{e}_i\otimes \mathbf{e}^j$$

My other question is if it is possible arriving to the following:

$$a = a^ib_j \mathbf{e}^i\otimes \mathbf{e}_j$$

Using matrix algebra? Is that possible?

I'm really confused. I've seen 2nd order tensors being written as $a^i_j$ and as $a_i^j$. What is the difference between them? Do they act the same way on vectors?

Comment: This type of tensor manipulation is known as Ricci Calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus

Comment: there, in the comments I suggest https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1047994/  as an observation of how in math this is settle, but now  I support to Vitor expecting someone could elaborate a bit more here with applications viewpoint. Going to upvote cuz the braveness asking now in PhysSE.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Staggered Indices ($\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$ vs. $\Lambda_\mu{}^\nu$) on Lorentz Transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255933/84967). See also [Lorentz invariance of the Minkowski metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230495/84967).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I don’t believe this is a duplicate for 1) I don’t speak specifically about Lorentz Transformations 2) I’m also interested in knowing if I can name these indices as covariant or contravariant and putting them in this order. 3) The cited question also doesn’t answer the question as to whether I can arrive to both constructions using matrix algebra. If i can’t, why not?

Comment: I just answered a very similar question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411015/matrix-multiplication-and-tensorial-summation-convention/411017#411017). Long story short, it's very easy to make a mistake while treating tensors as matrices, and I don't really think it's worth doing at all, but you can make it work.

Comment: @knzhou While that is indeed clarifying, I still do not think that it answers my question, just serves as some clarification about matrices vs tensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I have to say that **matrices are not tensors** or vice versa. Matrices are just arrays of numbers while tensors are invariant objects having co-variant or contra-variant components up to some basis.

By the way, the equalities you have written are not proper. If you have on one side a contra-variant tensor, then you need to have the other side contra-variant, as well. For instance, $x'_j = a^{ij} x_i$ should be $x'_j = a {}^i {}_j x_i$, or alike.

First, I would like to clarify some aspects of co-variant and contra-variant transformations of a tensor before I write the answer to the question about the order of indices, which would be trivial in the end.

### Tensors and their components

Tensors are not matrices or array of numbers. Tensors are objects on a vector space that does not change, as a whole, under a coordinate transformation. Vectors are one example for tensors, a vector is the same vector even if you express it in a different coordinate system. Only the components are transforming since the bases are changing, but not the whole thing.

So, expressing a tensor in terms of array of numbers implies some specific transformation properties on the components, depending on the transformation from one basis to another. These properties consist of **co-variant** and **contra-variant** transformations.

Let's assume we work in coordinate bases, $dx^i$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. So, tensors $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ could be written in different coordinate systems as follows:
\begin{align}
\tag{1.a}
\mathbf{A} &=A_i \, dx^i \\
\tag{1.b}
&= A'_i \, dx'^i
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\tag{2.a}
\mathbf{B} &= B^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \\
\tag{2.b}
&= B'^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^i}
\end{align}
where summation convention is used. I have just written the same tensors in different coordinate systems, primed or unprimed.

So, the primed components could be written in terms of unprimed components, respectively, as follows:

> $$ \tag{co-variant} A'_i = A_i \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x'^i} $$
>   $$ \tag{contra-variant} B'^i = B^i \frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^i} $$

where one needs to track the primes according to chain rule, when using the equality between (.a)'s and (.b)'s, respectively. Anything obeys these component-basis transformations which leaves the object unchanged is called a **tensor**.

Now, you can also express the tensor in any basis, even those non-coordinate ones, i.e., $\mathbf{e}^a = e {}^a_i dx^i$ and $\mathbf{e}_a = (e^{-1}) {}_a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ where the invertible map, $e {}^a_i (x)$, is called **tetrad field** or **vierbein** (in 4D). So, the new components would be $A_a = A_i (e^{-1}) {}_a^i$ and $B^a = B^i e {}^a_i$, respectively.

If you consider the proper version of the equality you have written, $v'_j = a {}^{i} {}_j v_i$, in this context I explained above, you can see how it becomes valid if you explicitly write the coordinate transformations.

### Order of the indices and the metric tensor

On the other hand, the relation between the co-variant and contra-variant components is handled via a map called **metric**:
$$
A_i = g_{ij} A^j
$$
and you can easily show that $g_{ij}$ are also components of a tensor, since both sides of this identity must transform co-variantly.

Now, let's take a second rank tensor, $T_{ij}$. The order of indices are important if the tensor is asymmetric, i.e., $T_{ij} \neq T_{ji}$. If you *raise up* the first or the second index via the metric, respectively,
$$
T {}^i {}_j = g^{ik} T_{kj} \\
T {}_j {}^i = g^{ik} T_{jk}
$$
it becomes obvious that they can only be equal if and only if $T_{ij}$ is symmetric in its indices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1: About my equalities being incorrect wrt the indexes, I've stated that I would correct them later.
I can't quite understand your answer. Could you explain why choosing $dx^i$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ as basis? And not some other basis vectors?
I also don't understand what you mean by "prime" components.
Another thing: In the last paragraph (which I think is supposed to answer the question afterall) It seems to me that you've explained the difference between $T^i_j$ and $T_j^i$. I'm sorry, I cant relate that to the difference between $T^i_j$ and $T_i^J$.

Comment: As for the bounty that expired, I will start a new one, since I was unable to access the site lately.

Comment: OK, thanks for the feedback, I will edit the answer.