# Difference between position of indexes in tensor notation (SR)

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

I am learning SR, and don't understand the difference between the following notations of a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$
$$\Lambda_{\mu\nu} , \Lambda_{\mu}\ ^\nu , \Lambda^{\mu\nu}$$

I know that they are related to the size of the tensor, but I am not sure how they are different

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255933/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230495/84967