# Spacing in indices, and relation to matrices, in special relativity notation

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

I have some general confusion regarding notation on tensors in special relativity, and how indices correspond to the matrix representation of second-rank tensors.

When one has a second-rank tensor $T_\mu^\nu$, is it *necessary* to stagger the indices, e.g. ${T_\mu}^\nu$ or ${T^\nu}_\mu$?

I also read elsewhere that it's common convention to take the first index as the row of the matrix representation of a second-rank tensor and the second index as a column. But when one has a mixed tensor like $T_\mu^\nu$, there seems to be no way to tell. It only seems to become a little more clear in products like $T_\mu^\nu p_\nu$, because you know which one has to be which in order for the product to make any sense from a linear algebra perspective ($\nu$ must be the column index).

So I guess my questions are

1. Are the above generally correct statements?
2. Is it convention, or necessary, or both/neither, to stagger indices (e.g. ${T_\mu}^\nu$), or is no spacing (e.g. $T_\mu^\nu$) valid?

Comment: You _always_ should stagger the indices. The common exceptions are the Dirac delta $\delta^\mu_\nu$ which is symmetric anyway, so switching the indices doesn't matter, and the Lorentz transformation $\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu}$, which aren't tensors anyway.

Comment: Also, thinking of row and column vectors becomes actively confusing the further you go. Whether something is a row or column vector is a completely convention-dependent and meaningless choice, akin to whether you like to write vectors in boldface or with an arrow over them. This is because the geometrical properties are already totally encoded in the index positions. If you insist on row/column conventions you'll be encoding the same information twice, which just makes things more complicated for no benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So why should the indices always be staggered? What meaning does the spacing contain? And why doesn't that meaning matter for $\Lambda$? Also, you said "the geometrical properties are already encoded in the index positions." I think maybe it is this correspondence that I'm trying to figure out; can you expand more? (Perhaps in an answer, since this would be a long comment.)

Comment: Uh... do you know what the abstract definition of a tensor is? That is, define a rank 2 tensor without using the words "index", "component", or "matrix".

Comment: I mean, in principle, I "know" that a tensor is a linear function of, most generally, some one-forms and some vectors into the real numbers. But I'm just starting to learn GR, and I think the issue is that, for some of the really basic proofs, I don't really understand the steps without seeing the corresponding matrices.

Comment: Then for a mixed rank $2$ tensor the index order just tells you whether the one-form is the first or the second argument. The one-form is the first argument if the upper index is first.

Comment: In particular, for example, a problem I am studying (not for homework) is to show that $A^{\overline{\alpha}} = {\Lambda^{\overline{\alpha}}}_\beta A^\beta$ and $P_{\overline{\beta}} = {\Lambda^\alpha}_{\overline{\beta}} P_\alpha$ are the same transformation if the matrix $\{{\Lambda^{\overline{\alpha}}}_\beta\}$ equals the transpose of its inverse. I don't really see the mapping of $\Lambda$, which I'm willing to take as some abstract object, into a matrix.

Comment: It's fine to write things out in components to see them clearer, but you can do this any way you want. You can take the first index to be the row, or the second index to be the row, doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is that the eventual matrix multiplication you write down matches the tensor contraction you actually want to compute.

Comment: That's different, $\Lambda$ is not a tensor, it just _is_ a matrix. So you're definitely right to think about it in matrix terms. For example, people will talk about "the transpose of $\Lambda$", language which makes no sense when applied to a tensor.

Comment: This means your real question actually doesn't match the question you wrote at all. You're not asking about how to turn tensors into matrices, you're asking about how to manipulate the weird, non-tensor matrix $\Lambda$. Try looking at [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255933/staggered-indices-lambda-mu-nu-vs-lambda-mu-nu-on-lorentz-trans?rq=1) and related ones, they might help!

Comment: Hold on, so, can you give me an example of a rank-2 tensor for which the order of the arguments matters? What I mean is, for rank 2, why should it matter whether I write down the one-form argument first or the vector argument first?

Comment: @flevinBombastus Suppose $F_{ab}=A_a B_b$ with $A\neq B$. What is $F_a^b$? Is is $A_a B^b$ or $A^b B_a$?

Comment: @flevinBombastus  Another thing that might help is to become familiar with how mathematicians define tensors (on smooth manifolds). The definition doesn't involve coordinates or indices at all, and the more familiar (to physicists) index-centric formalism can be deduced from it. From that perspective, the correctness of knzhou's comments becomes very clear.

Comment: Well, suppose you raise the index on $F^\mu_\nu$. Do you get $F^{\mu\nu}$ or $F^{\nu\mu}$? You would keep track of index order for non-mixed rank $2$ tensors, so to avoid losing information you need to do the same when they're mixed.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments, both of you. I guess there's some confusion on my part because, relative to the first example, in SR, $A_aB^b$ is the same as $A^bB_a$ for all $a,b$, right? But not so for a general metric, I guess? And from @knzhou's comment, thinking about it I'm not sure I see the difference between $F^{\mu\nu}$ and $F^{\nu\mu}$, but that may also be because I am still thinking strictly in SR?

Comment: @flevinBombastus Well, suppose $F^{01} = a$ and $F^{10} = b \neq a$. Then $F^{\mu\nu}$ and $F^{\nu\mu}$ aren't the same thing, because you get different answers when you plug in $\mu = 0$ and $\nu = 1$. This has nothing to do with SR.

Comment: I see... very good point. I should've been able to figure that out. As you can see, I just don't have much experience yet. Okay, I understand.

Comment: But for $\Lambda$, that's not a tensor because it doesn't require some arbitrary four-vector or one-form, only the relative velocity between the frames? Then does the order not matter because it's symmetric?

Answer (score 2):

The only time you don't need to stagger a tensor with two indices is when the unstaggered version is unambiguous, i.e. iff the tensor would be symmetric if its indices weren't mixed.

For example, the metric tensor (whose mixed version is the Kronecker delta) doesn't need staggering, and in general relativity the Ricci and stress tensors don't need it either.

On the other hand, the electromagnetic $F_{\mu\nu}$ is *anti*symmetric, so if it becomes mixed it must be staggered! (But it's probably best to write expressions so it isn't mixed.)

The rules for tensors with more indices are left as an exercise.

Comment: I prefer all the indices below: For me it is more clear and simple.

Comment: @Sebastiano With all lower indices, you can’t have contractions. So, for example, you can’t write Maxwell’s equations or the Lorentz force law.

Comment: @G.Smith You kinda can, but it starts looking silly, e.g. $x_iy_i=x_iy_j\eta_{ij}$.

Comment: @J.G.That is often done for spatial indices, but never for spacetime indices.

Comment: @G.Smith It *shouldn't* ever be done for spacetime indices, but I've definitely seen it done.

Comment: @G.Smith With extreme sincerity with so many indexes I go into extreme confusion because I do not work with tensors at school. I know a variant and counter-variant tensor when I invert the indices at the bottom. obviously I'm not an expert in the field but I always thank you very much for the kindness that you have towards me.